# Is the use of « ce » to refer to "he/she/it" forbidden in a comparative sentence?

Tags: pronoms

> **Il** est agile.
>
> vs : **C**’est agile.

I understand that in a non-comparative sentence, both « ce » and « il/elle » can be used, with the « il/elle » putting more emphasis on the idea of "he/she/it" than « ce » does.

> **Il** est bien plus agile qu'**il** n’en a l’air.
>
> vs : **C**’est bien plus agile qu'**il** n’en a l’air.

But in a comparative sentence, I wonder if the juxtaposition of « ce » and « il » is allowed or not?

Comment: Grammatically you can say "*c'est agile*" (although I challenge you to find a sentence with it...)  but you can't switch between *ce* and *il* as your like. You can say "*C'est plus fragile que ça en a l'air*" but you can't use it for a person. Because you have rules about when to use which, as the others said the rule applies to both (**C'** est plus ... que **ça** en a l'air).

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Interesting! The "ce" in "c’est agile" can be used to refer to a person, but the "ce" in "c'est plus fragile que ça en a l'air" cannot?

Comment: No, I'm saying "*c'*" in "*c'est agile*" cannot refer to a person, and that you'll have a hard time finding an inanimate object that can be agile...

Comment: I used *fragile* because *agile* doesn't really apply to object, but you can actually say "*c'est fragile*" : "it's fragile" and "*il est fragile*" : "he's weak" (very rough translation)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Oh, I had it confused with the "c'est un soldat" construction. So only a noun is allowed, but not an adjective like "agile" if you intend "ce" to refer to a person?

Comment: Yep, I was about to get to this part ! It's not just nouns, you can also say "*Qui c'est, ça ?*" "C'est mon frère, Marc.*" (by the way you must know that *noun* and *name* are the same word in French ;)

Comment: The answer by PERCE-NEIGE made me realise I talked too fast (again), for example you could say "*Un soldat, c'est agile*". It's not about being an object or not, it's about talking about a definite (le/lui/il,...) or undefinite (un). The subject can be inanimate but definite : "*Mon ordinateur, il est plus lent qu'avant*"... And sometimes you'll also have "*le/la*" AND "*c'est*", like in "*La montagne, c'est magnifique*". It's for concepts, ideas, abstract things, etc. (here *la montagne* is the general concepts of moutains, it's any mountain anywhere)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Do you mean: "Un soldat, c'est agile" vs "Le soldat, il est agile"?

Comment: Before we get moved to chat, "*Un soldat, c'est agile*" is one of the ways of saying "(all) soldiers are agile*" (in general), like "if you take a random soldier, he or she will be agile", while "*Le soldat, il est agile*" most often means "*this specific soldier is agile*", talking about an individual. (it can sometimes be used for general statements, in documentaries for example, but that's another story)

Comment: Without context, it's difficult to get an intuition about your proposal. Two pronouns are introduced without reference creating an uneasy feeling. If you include a background you will obtain a more comfortable discussion. For example, with an undefined monster (*ça*) and Paul (*lui*) who looks weak, we could try to judge: *C'est plus fort qu'il n'en a l'air (lui)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En fait, ça n'a strictement rien à voir avec le fait de comparer.

C'est en rapport avec "qui" ou "quoi", est remplacé par "il" ou "ce".

> *Il est beau.*

Gustave est beau: **Il** est beau.
C'est une personne.

> *C'est beau*

L'amour est beau: **C**'est beau.

C'est une chose, un sentiment, non une personne.

> <s>C’est bien plus agile qu'il n’en a l’air.</s>

Phrase incorrecte. Il faut dire:

> **Il** est bien plus agile qu'**il** n’en a l’air.

Peut-être as-tu rencontré des phrases du type:

> **C**'est plus beau qu'**il** ne le croît.

Mais dans ce cas "ce" et "il" ne réfèrent pas du tout à la même chose.

Pas de raison d'utiliser une fois "il", et une fois "ce". "Il" n'est pas une chose.

Je pense que tu confonds avec le *"il" impersonnel*, qui ne se réfère pas à une chose.

> Il est 3 heures. Il fait beau.

Quelques fois, dans des cas bien précis, on peut employer le "ce" alors que c'est un être vivant.

> Gédéon court. Il est agile.

Le "ce" est réservé à une chose, ou équivalent.

> Un lapin, **c**'est agile.

Bien que le lapin ne soit pas une chose, ici c'est un cas particulier, d'une expression. C'est un peu comme si on "chosifiait" le sujet pour faire une généralité.

> Un homme, **c**'est fort.

Hormis ce cas, on a bien en général:

> J'ai vu un petit lapin, **il** court dans les champs.

Comment: Le pronom *ce* sujet n'apparaît qu'avec le verbe ÊTRE, la question ne se pose pas avec COURIR...

Comment: Si on voulait utiliser le pronom neutre avec le verbe courir, dans ce cas "ce" devient "ça": ça court. C'est le même pronom neutre sous 2 formes différentes.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, you can use **ce** in a comparative sentence, but be consistent with your pronouns.

> <strike>**C**'est bien plus agile qu'**il** n'en a l'air</strike>

is incorrect. You should rather say:

> **C**'est bien plus agile que **ça** n'en a l'air

or

> **Il** est bien plus agile qu'**il** n'en a l'air

as you said

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with comparative sentences or not.

*Ce* and *il* are different, and designate two different things: an object for the first one and a male person for the latter.

Note that *ce* cannot be used as a reference to a person, just like *it* in English. So your example is grammatically correct, but depending on the context one option is to be used.

For your last question,

> I wonder if the juxtaposition of « ce » and « il » is allowed or not?

the answer is **no**.

What you are looking for is *cela*, or *ça* in short and less formal.

> **C**’est bien plus agile que **cela**/**ça** n’en a l’air.